# use foreach to set multiple session attributes

Tags: php, session, foreach

I'm working on member edit page, so for each html input I use sessions to echo values like:

```
value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['username']));?>
value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['email']));?>
```

etc... 
once member edits profile, i use query again to fetch new updated $results.

This is the old way i did to unset/set new sessions:

```
unset($_SESSION['user']); 
unset($_SESSION['email']); 
unset($_SESSION['first_name']); 
unset($_SESSION['last_name']); 
unset($_SESSION['birth_date']); 
unset($_SESSION['about_me']); 
unset($_SESSION['gender']);
unset($_SESSION['last_activity']);
unset($_SESSION['image_avatar']);   


$_SESSION['user'] = $result['user']; 
$_SESSION['email'] = $result['email']; 
$_SESSION['first_name'] = $result['first_name']; 
$_SESSION['last_name'] = $result['last_name']; 
$_SESSION['birth_date'] = $result['birth_date']; 
$_SESSION['about_me'] = $result['about_me']; 
$_SESSION['gender'] = $result['gender'];
$_SESSION['last_activity'] = $result['last_activity'];
$_SESSION['image_avatar'] = $result['image_avatar'];
```

but i wanted less code lines and tried making foreach like this:

```
    foreach($result as $key => $value) {
        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
    }

    foreach($result as $key => $value) {
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    }
```

using foreach works fine, but my only questions is, if this right way to do it?

Comment: Those are called _session attributes_ not sessions. Those attributes are being set in the same session.

Comment: thanks @developerwjk ill edit title not to confuse others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only improvement I can think of is to do it all in one foreach and there is no need to unset a value you are going to replace anyway

```
foreach($result as $key => $value) {
    // not necessary if you are going to replace the value anyway
    //unset($_SESSION[$key]);
    $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
}
```

Comment: you are totally right, i don't know what i was thinking. thank you